# asp.net html href send query string

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a this html code :

```
<li><a href="Password.aspx" accesskey="2"  >مشاهده</a></li>
```

I want when i click on the `li`,to redirect other page,for example:

```
Response.Redirect("ManagerAdd.aspx");
```

and i want to send the query string to ManagerAdd page, for example:

```
Response.Redirect("ManagerAdd.aspx?rid=" + r_id.ToString());
```

my `r_id` get from this `webform`,for example:

how can i write this on li html?

```
<li><a href="ManagerAddFood.aspx?rid=" + r_id.ToString() accesskey="2"  >مشاهده منو</a></li>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    t1 = Request.QueryString["id"];
}
```

and i want to get id from form1 load event and send manageradd.aspx with string query.

Comment: Your query string variable is rid(Response.Redirect("ManagerAdd.aspx?rid=" + r_id.ToString());) so you should access like Request.QueryString["rid"].

Comment: so what? what is the question?

Comment: @zkanoca how can define click event on li html?

Comment: @zkanoca i update my question,please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least you can use

```
<li><a href="ManagerAddFood.aspx?rid=<%=Request.QueryString["r_id"];%>" accesskey="2">مشاهده منو</a></li>
```

OR

You can give `id="link1"` and `runat="server"` attributes to `<a>` element and make the link at code behind.

```
<li><a id="link1" runat="server" accesskey="2">مشاهده منو</a></li>
```

**It is important that all items have unique id values.**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    //link1.Attributes["href"] = "ManagerAddFood.aspx?rid=" + r_id.ToString()";
    link1.Attributes["href"] = "ManagerAddFood.aspx?rid=" + Request.QueryString["r_id"];
}
```

Comment: thanks,i write your code,but i get this error:r_id is inaccesible due to its protection level

Comment: are you sure it is `r_id` in your own code? It is not `t1`, right?

Comment: yes i'm sure,and this my code in load event:r_id = query.r_id.ToString();

Comment: thanks for pay attention to my problem my dear friend,my problem solve with your help,tnx.

Comment: i'm near to you!,i'm from iran-tabriz,my distance from turkey-Van is 400km